# PHP Sum Like Elements

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have a PHP array, I'd like to sum all of the values for each recurring element and then return just one final array with the sum totals... Here's the sample array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [purchase_amount] => 5000.00
        [listing_price] => 5000.00
        [home_warranty_cost] => 10.00
        [emd] => 100.00
        [fee] => 10.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [purchase_amount] => 0.00
        [listing_price] => 0.00
        [home_warranty_cost] => 10.00
        [emd] => 100.00
        [fee] => 10.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [purchase_amount] => 15000.00
        [listing_price] => 15000.00
        [home_warranty_cost] => 10.00
        [emd] => 100.00
        [fee] => 10.00
    )
```

And I'd like to just have this in the end...

```
    (
        [purchase_amount] => 20000.00
        [listing_price] => 20000.00
        [home_warranty_cost] => 30.00
        [earnest_money_amount] => 300.00
        [tc_fee] => 30.00
    )
```

Is there a simple function to do this or do I need to write a for loop?

Comment: What have you tried, this can be done in a simple foreach loop.

Comment: There is no built-in function to do this, you'll have to write a loop.

Comment: `for each recurring element` Does that mean that if one of the arrays contains a key that does not exists in the others you should also see that in the result?

Answer (score 3):

This is a good fit for `array_reduce`[[doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)], which works regardless of your key names.

The callback function for `array_reduce` is applied to every element of the input array and takes an accumulator `$carry` and current element `$item`. If the accumulator is null, this is the first element in the reduction process so we can make a direct assignment. Otherwise, loop over the current element's entries and add values to the accumulator.

```
array_reduce($data, function ($carry, $item) {
   if (!$carry) {
      $carry = $item;
   }  
   else {
      foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
          $carry[$k] += $v;
      }
   }

   return $carry;
});
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [purchase_amount] => 20000
    [listing_price] => 20000
    [home_warranty_cost] => 30
    [emd] => 300
    [fee] => 30
)
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/VapidLeftRepository)

Comment: Awesome! I knew there had to be some sort of PHP function. Thanks!

Comment: It would also be nice if you added some comments or named the variables properly. The docs use `$carry` and `$item`.

Comment: I can follow the docs. I do think accumulator is clearer than `$carry`, though, which has mathematical connotations that aren't accurate (you don't always carry when adding, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this. There is still one loops over the keys, but that's necessary to not list all fields everytime...

```
$sums = array_reduce($data, function ($carry, $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value)
    {
        $carry[$key] = array_key_exists($key, $carry) ? $carry[$key] + $item[$key] : 0;
    }

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

[Working example](https://3v4l.org/bBt9f) here.